# Maven maven-war-plugin not replacing values in web.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Maven version: 3.5.4

**My web directory is not in the standard location.  It is in /web**

Maven War config

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <!--
                        Filter these files to look for ${my.maven.property} to replace them
                        at build time with a maven property value
                    -->
                    <resource>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <directory>web/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <warSourceDirectory>web</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webXml>web/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <packagingExcludes>
                   ${exclude.files.on.build}
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

properties snippet from pom.xml

```
  <properties>
       ...

       <!-- web.xml vars -->
       <web.session.cookie.secure>true</web.session.cookie.secure> <!-- session cookie only sent over https -->
      ...
 </properties>
```

web.xml snippet

```
   <cookie-config>
        ...
        <secure>${web.session.cookie.secure}</secure>
        ...
    </cookie-config>
```

The property "${web.session.cookie.secure}" is not being replaced in the web.xml, and the property name is retained in the war file generated.  I have not been able to pinpoint the configuration error.  I am working in Intellij and get the same result whether I build the artifact off the intellij menu, or issue the mvn war:exploded command.

I am assuming that it may have something to do with the web directory location and a missing configuration item.  The maven build runs as expected other than the issue with the properties not being replaced in the output.

Any ideas as to why the replacements would not be taking place using the filtering of the maven-war-plugin?

Comment: Have you checked your target directory path? Try <directory>${basedir}/web/WEB-INF</directory> and also look in the effective-pom how the path is being interpreted.

Comment: @briadeus wow, unbelievable, spent 4+ hours on that today!  That has resolved the issue.  Please post as the answer and I will accept it.  Thank you

Comment: Well, this did work in my local env, but it is not working on the jenkins build which is on a Linux box.  Separate issue.... ugg

Comment: Glad it helped. I added the answer for reference. It behaves the same on Linux, so the problem is probably something else. Try checking the effective-pom or running "mvn clean install -X" for debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `maven-war-plugin` uses `${basedir}` as the location of the pom, so the target directory for filtering should be referenced via relative path from there.

```
<resource>
  <filtering>true</filtering>
  <directory>${basedir}/web/WEB-INF</directory>
  <includes>
    <include>**/web.xml</include>
  </includes>
</resource>
```

The actuall path could be examined in `mvn help:effective-pom`.